# Rails Choose 3 different posts randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

hey everyone so I'm working on a small blog and there is a new section a want to add. An "editor's choice" section so basically i want to add a small div that contains 3 randomly pick posts from the blog. The problem is I do not know how to show only three randomely select titles from all the posts. I tried @posts.sample(3) and that shows the entire record of the Post. I just want to show the title only.
I want to show the editors choice on the posts index view
Schema

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "nickname"
  end
```

Posts_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(posts_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    if @post.save
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.update(posts_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  def destroy
    if @post.destroy
      redirect_to posts_path
    end
  end

  private

  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :user_id, :image, :nickname)
  end

  def current
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

end
```

post_index.html.erb

```
<%= render "layouts/blog_header" %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="posts">
    <div>
      <% unless !post.image.attached? %>
        <%= image_tag post.image, class: "post-index-image" %><br>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <p class="post-index-title"><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post.id), class: "post-index-title" %></p>
    <p>Published by: <strong><%= post.user.nickname %></strong></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= @posts.sample(3) %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `@posts.sample.pluck(:title)` - should work :)

Answer (score 3):

I would start with something like this when you are using PostgreSQL:

```
@posts.order('RANDOM()').limit(3)
```

or when you are on MySQL:

```
@posts.order('RAND()').limit(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should do what you want:

```
@posts.sample(3).pluck(:title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

> @posts.pluck(:title).sample(3)

More efficient than

> @posts.sample(3).pluck(:title)